# Significance of /dev/null in Web Servers?

Tags: webserver, mongrel, dev-null

Recently I've heard a bit about the implementation (or rather, use of) /dev/null in Mongrel2, as well as other projects. However, I've never seen it explained what this actually means.

What does this mean, and why is it good for scalability (as I've seen it be claimed)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki//dev/null) :-) The Mongrel2 "support" was a joke (see the [change](http://mongrel2.org/info/72dae993fc), which was later [removed](http://mongrel2.org/vinfo/a8645888dfef517a5aae15582ba9fe062ee288d1)).

Being serious though, `/dev/null` is useful when you want to discard output from processes. You can redirect output to it, for example, and the kernel will just discard that output.

Comment: Ah thank you. Guess I missed the joke; it must have been in the code somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

/dev/null is a virtual device on UNIX systems which basically drops all data sent to it.